# Creating a newcommand to draw base ten blocks

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

[Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561252/tikz-defining-a-ones-tenths-hundredths-block) made some great code for base ten blocks and I've been trying to use it to automatically generate representations of 2-digit numbers.

```
%%Base 10 Blocks
\tikzset {
    node distance=.1cm,
    hundred/.style={
        draw,
        minimum size=1cm,
        inner sep=0pt
        },
    tenv/.style={
        line width=0.1mm,
        fill=red,
        draw,
        minimum height=1cm,
        minimum width=0.1cm,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
    tenthh/.style={
        draw,
        minimum height=0.1cm,
        minimum width=1cm,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
    unitone/.style={
         line width=0.1mm,
        draw,
        minimum size=0.1cm,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
   base graph/.pic={
        \node[hundred] (00) {};
        \node[hundred, below=of 00] (10) {};
        \node[tenthh, below=of 10] (20) {};
        \foreach \i [count=\xi, remember=\xi as \lasti (initially 0)] in {1,2,3,4} 
          \node[tenv, right=of 0\lasti] (0\xi) {};         
        \path (00.north west) -- (20.south west) node[midway, left] {2.1} ;
        \path (00.north west) -- (04.north east) node[midway, above] {1.4} ;
        }
    }
```

Here's some code I've made to generate the number 37

```
 \begin{center} \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=3}]
 \foreach \y in {-0.95,-0.85,...,-0.35}{
 \node[unitone] at (0.1,\y){};}
 \foreach \x in {-0.5,-0.3,...,-0.1}{
 \node[tenv] at (\x,-0.5){};}
 \end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
```

It looks the part ...

[image]

Though was very fiddly and created in excel.

I would love to have code like `\basetenpic{7}{3}` that automatically creates a similar picture. (Where the ones value goes first to allow for more place value positions, like `\basetenpic{2}{0}{3}` that would make a picture with 3 hundreds followed by 2 ones ...)

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't there be gaps between the boxes of the ones as well?

Comment: It's really hard (impossible?) to have a macro `\basetenpic{7}`, `\basetenpic{7}{3}`, `\basetenpic{7}{3}{2}`, because TeX can't tell if the macro is done, or has another argument coming.  It's easier to put everything into one argument, and much easier to always have three arguments.

Comment: with the french package ProfCollege, lots of macros... for exemple \RepresenterEntier{37}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- defined lengths `\unitsize` and `\unitsep`
- use `foreach` to draw nodes
- use `\ifnumgreater{\tens}{0}{}{}` etc. to check if which blocks should be drawn
- I also thought about using just the number as one parameter, as an extension, but then I saw that this is already done in Jasper's answer. So I just added a wrapper function `\basetenpicx{<number>}`.

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\unitsize}
\setlength{\unitsize}{3mm}

\newlength{\unitsep}
\setlength{\unitsep}{3mm}

% Base 10 Blocks
\tikzset {
    node distance=\unitsep,
    hundred/.style={
        draw,
        fill=yellow,
        anchor=south west,
        minimum size=10*\unitsize,
        inner sep=0pt
    },
    tenv/.style={
        anchor=south west,
        line width=0.1mm,
        fill=red,
        draw,
        minimum height=10*\unitsize,
        minimum width=\unitsize,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
    tenthh/.style={
        anchor=south west,
        draw,
        minimum height=\unitsize,
        minimum width=10*\unitsize,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
    unitone/.style={
        anchor=south west,
        line width=0.1mm,
        draw,
        minimum size=\unitsize,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
}

\newcommand{\basetenpic}[3]{
    \edef\ones{#1}
    \edef\tens{#2}
    \edef\hundreds{#3}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % uncomment this to have the same height
        %\node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,10*\unitsize) {};
        % one
        \ifnumgreater{\ones}{0}{
            \foreach \i in {1, ..., \ones}{
                \node[unitone] at ({\hundreds*(10*\unitsize+\unitsep) + \tens*(\unitsize+\unitsep)}, {(\i-1)*\unitsize}) {};
            }
        }{}
        % ten
        \ifnumgreater{\tens}{0}{
            \foreach \i in {1, ..., \tens}{
                \node[tenv] at ({\hundreds*(10*\unitsize+\unitsep) + (\i-1)*(\unitsize+\unitsep)}, 0) {};
            }
        }{}
        % hundret
        \ifnumgreater{\hundreds}{0}{
            \foreach \i in {1, ..., \hundreds}{
                \node[hundred] at ({(\i-1)*(10*\unitsize+\unitsep)}, 0) {};
            }
        }{}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}

\newcommand{\basetenpicx}[1]{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ones}{mod(#1, 10)}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tens}{mod(#1 - \ones, 100)/10}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\hundreds}{mod(#1 - \tens - \ones, 1000)/100}
    \basetenpic{\ones}{\tens}{\hundreds}
}

\begin{document}

\obeylines
\verb|\basetenpic{7}{0}{0}|:
\basetenpic{7}{0}{0}

\verb|\basetenpic{7}{3}{0}|:
\basetenpic{7}{3}{0}

\verb|\basetenpicx{203}|:
\basetenpicx{203}

\verb|\basetenpicx{60}|:
\basetenpicx{60}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works so well, thank you so much for spending the time to write this wonderful code. This will save me so much time!!

Comment: Hello again, is there a way to modify this code so even if tikzpicture for single digit numbers, like \basetenpicx{4} has the same overall height as \basetenpicx{10}? Thank you :)

Comment: You could add `\node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,10*\unitsize) {};` to the `tikzpicture` environment, to draw an invisible node that is considered for the size of the image. Another option would be adding `\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0,10*\unitsize);`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly!

Comment: Hello, I've just been using the code again (still a massive time saver!) though noticed that a bug occurs when there are no ones digit. For example,   \basetenpicx{60} has 6 tens and then 2 ones but a little off centre. Is there a way to adapt the code so no ones are produced when a number doesn't have any ones? Thanks so much!

Comment: @WendyTaylor I solved the bug. There was missing an if condition that tests if `\ones` > 0 around the first `\foreach` loop. Therefore, the `\foreach` loop was executed for `{1, ..., 0}` (i.e. 1 and 0). I added `\basetenpicx{60}` as an example. By the way: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) in comments.

Comment: Thanks so much! I’m starting to understand the code more myself now too. A huge help!

Answer (score 4):

I think, an even nicer approach than to have a macro that accepts one, two or three arguments would be to just let PGF do the math. This way, you just type arbitrary numbers between 1 and 999 into the single argument of the macro `\basetenpic` and the number of boxes will be calculated automatically.

I would also probably adjust the sizes of the boxes and gaps so that 10 smaller boxes (including the gaps) have the same width or height as one larger box. (Of course, as @dexteritas pointed out, it is not possible to match the areas of the different boxes and the values they represent while, at the same time, having 10 one-boxes including the gaps match the height of 1 ten-box.)

The following would output such boxes. You may want to style the different boxes according to your taste, for example, fill them yellow or whatever. The macro takes an optional argument for adding custom options to the `tikzpicture` for styling:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
    basetenpic/.style={
        node distance=0.05cm,
        every node/.style={
            draw,
            line width=0.01cm,
            inner sep=0pt,
        },
        hundreds/.style={
            % = 10 x height of boxes + 9 x line width + 9 x gap
            % = 10 x 0.1cm + 9 x 0.01cm + 9 x 0.05cm
            minimum size=1.54cm,
        },
        tens/.style={
            minimum height=1.54cm,
            minimum width=0.1cm,
        },
        ones/.style={
            minimum size=0.1cm,
        }
    }
}

\newcounter{boxcount}
\newcommand{\basetenpic}[2][]{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ones}{mod(#2, 10)}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tens}{mod(#2 - \ones, 100)/10}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\hundreds}{mod(#2 - \tens - \ones, 1000)/100}
    \setcounter{boxcount}{0}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[basetenpic, #1]
        \coordinate (n0) at (0,0);
        \ifnum\hundreds>0\relax
            \foreach \i [evaluate={\theboxcount as \lastboxcount}] in {1,...,\hundreds} {
                \stepcounter{boxcount}
                \node[right=of n\lastboxcount, hundreds] (n\theboxcount) {};
            }
        \fi
        \ifnum\tens>0\relax
            \foreach \i [evaluate={\theboxcount as \lastboxcount}] in {1,...,\tens} {
                \stepcounter{boxcount}
                \node[right=of n\lastboxcount, tens] (n\theboxcount) {};
            }
        \fi
        \ifnum\ones>0\relax
            \foreach \i [evaluate={\theboxcount as \lastboxcount}] in {1,...,\ones} {
                \stepcounter{boxcount}
                \ifnum\i=1\relax
                    \node[right=of n\lastboxcount.south east, anchor=south west, ones] (n\theboxcount) {};
                \else
                    \node[above=of n\lastboxcount, ones] (n\theboxcount) {};
                \fi
            }
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    
\basetenpic{26}

\basetenpic{302}

\basetenpic[hundreds/.append style={fill=yellow}]{137}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The original answer you link to creates a `pic`, while this solution outputs a full `tikzpicture`. But it is not too complicated to convert one into another.

---

If you remove the gaps, the areas of the boxes will have the exact relation to each other (that is the box for the tens will be 10 times the area of one small box etc). I would, however, for the sake of consistency, remove the gaps alltogether. You can change the `\tikzset` part of the above MWE by the following:

```
\tikzset{
    basetenpic/.style={
        % = minus half the line width    
        node distance=-0.005cm,
        every node/.style={
            draw,
            line width=0.01cm,
            inner sep=0pt,
        },
        hundreds/.style={
            minimum size=1cm,
        },
        tens/.style={
            minimum height=1cm,
            minimum width=0.1cm,
        },
        ones/.style={
            minimum size=0.1cm,
        }
    }
}
```

Example result:

[image]

Comment: I think the gaps between the ones are problematic, because then the area doesn't match anymore.

Comment: @dexteritas Ah, due to the line width, right?

Comment: Because of the gaps (and size of 1.55cm instead of 1cm). The area of the box of 10 is therefore no longer 10 times as large as the area of the box of one. I think you should theoretically be able to put the boxes on top of each other so that it fits. But I think this depends on what you want.

Comment: @dexteritas No, you are right. Actually, the box of 10 should be 1.45cm high, because 10 × 0.1cm (height of box of 1) + 9 × 0.05cm (gap). But somehow this does not fit. And this is probably due to the line width of the boxes of 1

Comment: That's not what I meant ;) I was only interested in the area in relation to the boxes. Now the ten-box has 15.5 times the area of a one-box instead of 10 times, which means that the boxes cannot be visually placed on top of each other without there being gaps.

Comment: @dexteritas Sorry, now I get you! Yes, you are right. The area is not a representation of the values this way. But since there are gaps between the boxes of 10, I tought, it would be consistent to also have gaps between the boxes of 1. I adjusted the calculation and the sizes now, so that it fits. Of course, a drawback is: if you want to adjust the gaps or the sizes of the boxes, you would need to calculate everything again. So, your approach with using macros to store the width of the gaps is surely a good thing!

Comment: Thanks so much for writing this up. Minimising the gaps between the ones is really helpful as it helps students see that 10 ones is exactly equal to 1 ten.

Comment: @WendyTaylor I added an example how to change the width of the gaps to zero. In the end you need to do some calculations to make the sizes of the boxes fit. I hope, this can help.

Comment: Thanks so much @JasperHabicht :)